# Gluing complex smooth projective varieties along homeomorphic open subsets

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

Let $X$ and $Y$ be smooth projective varieties over $\mathbb C$. Suppose $U\subset X$ and $V\subset Y$ are open subsets that are homeomorphic. Are there any reasonable way to glue $X$ and $Y$ along the opens so that it remembers more than just topology? If $U$ and $V$ are isomorphic as varieties, we can define a usual gluing of schemes, but for example I am wondering if there is some special analytic results over $\mathbb C$ that enables gluing of homeomorphic opens. I am expecting some possible restrictions on dimension due to some exotic structures although I am not an expert.

Edit: It is still helpful for me if a geometric object we get after gluing is not an algebraic variety. I am also wondering what we can say about $X\cup Y$ as a topological space more than just it should be quasi-compact, locally spectral (locally Euclidian), noetherian etc.

Comment: It seems a fundamental obstruction that to call such a thing as gluing you would want $U = V$ as subsets of $X \cup Y$ but in general you have $U \not\cong V$ as varieties.

Comment: Thank you for your comment and I agree with your obstruction. I am wondering if there still can be some additional information on $X \cup Y$ that does not necessarily fully recover $X$ and $Y$ (or in other words, weaken structures of $X$ and $Y$ if necessary so that $U=V$).